# Convert a Negative Number to a string then back to a negative Number

Tags: javascript

```
function sumDigits(num) {
  var newStr = num.toString();
  var result = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<newStr.length; i++) {
    result += Number(newStr[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

var output = sumDigits(-1148);
console.log(output); // --> -14
```

Trying to sum the individual digits in this problem. However, when negative numbers are involved the function falls apart. This is because when you use toString() converts the negative-sign as a value in the newStr. For example, newStr[0] === '-' in this case. Anyway to work around this? Preferably using the Number() function

Answer (score 2):

You could work with the absolute value and apply the sign later to the result.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
    var newStr = Math.abs(num).toString(),
        result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        result += Number(newStr[i]);
    }

    return (num > 0 || -1) * result;
}

var output = sumDigits(-1148);
console.log(output); // --> -14
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `String(), Array.prototype.reduce(), Math.abs(), spread syntax and ternary operator` to get the desired result.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  const number = Math.abs(num),
        sum = [...String(number)].reduce((acc, n) => acc + parseInt(n), 0);
  return num >= 0 ? sum : -1 * sum;
}

const output1 = sumDigits(-1148);
console.log(output1); // --> -14
const output2 = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output2); // --> 14
```